# How is a spark application accessing a file/directory in Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pyspark, amazon-emr

say I want to load a .csv file in a S3 bucket as a dataframe

I know there's a code

```
spark.read.format('csv').load("s3://path/file.csv")
```

But I want to know what happenes behind the scene? Or what exactly makes this happen? I was asked this question in an interview and couldn't answer it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not know what the interviewers expected but here goes my answer.

It will create a DataFrame with [BaseRelation](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-BaseRelation.html) implementing [HadoopFsRelation](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-BaseRelation-HadoopFsRelation.html) because you are trying to access a file (with databases you would be using [JDBCRelation](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-JDBCRelation.html)).

The HadoopFsRelation will be using [CsvFileFormat](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-CSVFileFormat.html) which ends up using [CSVDataSource](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVDataSource.scala) what will enable you to read the CSV file for processing its data.